Is it legal to define a copy constructor for the pure abstract class?
Background:
I intend to use builder pattern to create a branch of concreate classes whose parent classes are the same. Since all the said concreate classes to be instantiated all need a same setting method, say
void set_mgr(Mgr&);,
so it seems that there should be a member variable(whose type is Mgr*) in the pure abstract class. And a copy constructor is needed in the pure abstract class to deal with the said member variable.
I have carefully read this question on the stackoverflow. There is even an example to show it's legal to implement a copy constructor for a pure abstract class, but the code snippet actually could not be compiled at all.

the snippet only declares function but don't define them. Here is a working one

These are [tag:linker-errors]. Ergo it's legal, you just forgot to write some code.

There is no such thing as a "pure abstract class". A virtual function can be marked as "pure virtual" with = 0 after its declaration. Any class that has one or more pure virtual functions is an "abstract class".

Aside from being incomplete, abstract classes are no different from ordinary classes; you cannot just explicitly instantiate them. But runtime polymorphism (with virtual functions) is not investigated too much in C++. So, we don't have enough good-practice idioms and patterns for it. Command pattern and type-erasure are commonly used in places where runtime polymorphism is needed. Factory pattern is implemented via std::variant & so on. There are just so many ways around virtual functions. We often find classical OO too restrictive in C++.
